How can I apply Fixed Effect Regression using FixedEffectModel on my dataset?
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from fixedeffect.iv import iv2sls, ivgmm, ivtest
from fixedeffect.fe import fixedeffect, did, getfe
from fixedeffect.utils.panel_dgp import gen_data
file_path = 'mix.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file_path)
# Melt the dataframe to long format
df_long = pd.melt(df, 
              id_vars=['Series Name', 'Series Code', 'Country Name', 'Country Code'], 
              value_vars=['YR2019 [YR2019]', 'YR2018 [YR2018]', 'YR2017 [YR2017]', 
                          'YR2016 [YR2016]', 'YR2015 [YR2015]', 'YR2014 [YR2014]', 
                          'YR2013 [YR2013]', 'YR2012 [YR2012]', 'YR2011 [YR2011]', 
                          'YR2010 [YR2010]'], 
              var_name='Year', 
              value_name='Value')

# Clean up column names
df_long['Year'] = df_long['Year'].str.extract('(\d{4})').astype(int)
df_long['Country Code'] = df_long['Country Code'].astype(str)
df_long['id'] = df_long['Country Code'] + '_' + df_long['Year'].astype(str)
df_long = df_long.dropna(subset=['Value'])
# Convert 'Value' to numeric
df_long['Value'] = pd.to_numeric(df_long['Value'], errors='coerce')

tried using https://pypi.org/project/FixedEffectModel/
dependent variable is Operational self Sufficiency



